# How to create a SQL Server linked Server with Local SQL Server Authentication User to a remote Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I need to create a Linked Server from Server A that uses a SQL Server Authentication to a Server B that uses a Windows Authentication.

Is the "impersonation" possible?

If "YES" what options, config should I pick?

[image]

Comment: After some Google it looks like this is not possible (https://itectec.com/database/sql-server-linked-server-with-windows-authentication-permissions/).

Comment: Which security context do you want the connection under? Will the user authenticate or the server authenticate? It's very unclear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Charlieface the Linked Server has to go from Server A that has a user registered using SQL Authentication to a user in Server B that uses Windows Authentication. I am trying to impersonate the user that uses Windows Authentication.

Comment: No this cannot be done. You can only use Windows Auth if the login exists on both servers and you are connecting to Server A using that login

Comment: thx @Charlieface you confirmed my suspicion. Do you want to make that as an answer so I can vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented, this is not possible.

If you do not want to do impersonation (using the *locally* logged-in user on Server A to authenticate to Server B), you must specify a SQL Server Authentication login, you cannot authenticate using Windows Authentication.

[The docs for SSMS say:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

> **Remote User**
> Use the remote user to map user defined in **Local login**. The **Remote User** must be a SQL Server Authentication login on the remote server.

[And for `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedsrvlogin-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)

> `[ @rmtuser = ] 'rmtuser'`
> Is the remote login used to connect to `rmtsrvname` when `@useself` is `FALSE`. When the remote server is an instance of SQL Server that does not use Windows Authentication, `rmtuser` is a SQL Server login.